# Python CSV writing one column per character for some reason

Tags: python

I keep getting an output (image below) which writes one character per column in excel. What am I doing wrong?

[Output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prc9V.png)

```
r= requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

listing_title= soup.find_all("div",{"class":"listingTitle"})

car_info_data =  soup.find_all("li",{"class": "titleCol"})

with open('testinggggg.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for item in car_info_data:     #Car name ;
        print(str(item.contents[1].text))
        writer.writerow(str(item.contents[1].text))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass *a list of column values* into the `writerow()`, but currently you are passing a string. Replace:

```
writer.writerow(str(item.contents[1].text))
```

with:

```
writer.writerow([str(item.contents[1].text)])
```

Comment: Thanks :) just wondering, how would i get the data to print to the second column if I use a second writer.writerow([str(item.contents[2].text)]) in the loop ? instead of both printing in the same column

Comment: @Mus sure, the `writer.writerow([str(item.contents[1].text), str(item.contents[2].text)])` should work.